# Binding an object's method in another class's property with different arguments

Tags: javascript, bind

*This is a stripped down version of a file i'm working on.*

So, there's this Object that has this method,

```
const A = {
          dispatchEvent(el, component, eventName, ...args) {
          el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("gsuiEvents", {
              bubbles: true,
              detail: { component, eventName, args },
          })
     );
 }
```

and there's

```
class B extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {}
        super();
        this._dispatch = A.dispatchEvent.bind(
          null,
          this,
          "someItem"
        );

     _oninputProp(prop, val) {
        this._dispatch("liveChange", prop, val);
     }
}
```

If you look at the **Class B** , the dispatchEvent method being bound has (null, this, "someItem")
as the parameters whereas on **Object A**, there's ***(el, component , eventName, ...args)***.

I want to understand whats going on. Will the **this._dispatch** property have the function that's contained in **Object A** ?

also, if you look at the arguments on **Class B**'s ***_oninputProp()*** method, there's different type of arguments which is different from **Object A**'s ***dispatchEvent()*** method.

Sorry for such a question, please bear with me.
Thank you.

Comment: "Will the this._dispatch property have the function that's contained in Object A?"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind should answer this.

Comment: The first argument to `bind` is whatever the bound function will use as `this`. So if you were to invoke a function on `this` in the `A.dispatchEvent` function then it would break.

Comment: For your second question: the arguments `"liveChange", prop, val` will map to `el, component, eventName` respectively. Which makes me there's some error with how you map your arguments.

Comment: Thank you, Chris! You saved me big time. Also, i just read the other two comments right after posting this reply. I read the MDN and it was all there. Thank you!!

Comment: some error?? Do you mean the extra (...args). Wouldn't that be ignored since theres no more params?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Your setup is fine. Invoking `this._dispatch("liveChange", prop, val);` will call `A.dispatchEvent` with `this` (i.e. the element's pointer to it's `this`) as `el`, `"someItem"` as `component`, `"liveChange"` as `eventName`, `prop` and `val` as `...args`

Comment: Exactly. I'm very excited finally gettting this sorted out. Thank you for your precious time. @Christian

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to set it up:

```
const A = {
          dispatchEvent(component, eventName, ...args) {
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("gsuiEvents", {
              bubbles: true,
              detail: { component, eventName, args },
          })
     );
 }

class B extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {}
        super();
        this._dispatch = A.dispatchEvent.bind(
          this,
          "someItem"
        );

     _oninputProp(prop, val) {
        this._dispatch("liveChange", prop, val);
     }
}
```

The first argument to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is whatever the bound function will use as `this`.

In your case you want to invoke `dispatchEvent` on the element that made the binding, i.e. the instance of class B.

So to achieve this you should pass the element's `this` to be used as `this` in the bound function.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are all correct. Whats happening here is this,

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}
 
const list1 = list(1, 2, 3);
//  [1, 2, 3]
   
// Create a function with a preset leading argument
const leadingThirtysevenList = list.bind(null, 37);

const list2 = leadingThirtysevenList(); 
//  [37]

const list3 = leadingThirtysevenList(1, 2, 3); 
//  [37, 1, 2, 3]
```

All thanks to your MDN reference link. I was in the dark with this and all i needed was clarity.
Thank you again, Chris!